# Pause and resume REST calls

Tags: java, rest, oracle-maf

I am using `RestServiceAdapter.setRequestMethod()` to download an image from a server.

Is it possible to do pause and resume operations while downloading?

Comment: hi, what if you pause thread?

Comment: I tried using   setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + file.length() + "-") for HTTPConnection, But initially if only 32 bytes is downloaded, on resuming the total length of downloaded data is shown as actual length+ 32.